# Amazon S3 bucket policy for referer condition on specific folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to use condition of `StringLike aws:Referer` for a particular folder and make rest of the folder publicly accessible.

Here is my bucket policy:

```
  {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "AddPerm",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": "s3:GetObject",
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/folderName/*"
           ]
       },
       {
           "Sid": "",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": "s3:GetObject",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/folderName/users/*",
           "Condition": {
               "StringLike": {
                   "aws:Referer": [
                       "https://example.com/*"
                   ]
               }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

When I am using above policy, it is not working with first one.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working with first one"?

Comment: both condition not working simultaneously.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein got it we can't use more than one  "allow"  Effect in a bucket policy.

Comment: No, you CAN use more than one Allow. For example, you could do an Allow on `folder1` and another on `folder2`. However, you wanted to grant access to `folder1/*` but restrict a sub-path within `folder1`, which **contradicts** the first policy.

Comment: thanks, I got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below policy:

```
{
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/folderName/users/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your policy is granting `GetObject` access for anything in the `folderName` path of your bucket. This *includes* `folderName/users/*`.

Therefore, the second part of your policy is not being used (since the first policy is already granting access to the `folderName/users/*` path.

You could solve it by using different buckets, or you could convert the second policy into a `Deny` with `StringNotLike` (effectively saying that access is denied to `folderName/users/*` if the referer is not `example.com`.

Frankly, your policy looks strange because it is granting access to the entire `users` path hierarchy, which probably isn't what you'd want it to do. (I'm assuming you'd want to grant access only to a particular user's data based upon who is accessing your application.)

Please note that `referer` is **not secure** — it is easy to fake this value in a browser and in web-scraping softare.

Comment: hi @John Rotenstein now i want to add aws vpc condition on my bucket policy. it is not working.  refer my policy:

Comment: my policy is :   {
            "Sid": "Allow hh ",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/folderName/users/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://face.com/*",
                        "https://kola.com/*"
                    ]
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                   "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-1a2b3c4d"
                }
            }
        }

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to allow access from a particular aws VPC  and given domain

Comment: refer this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html

Comment: Referer is typically used to include content when being viewed from a particular website. For example, only allow pictures to be retrieved when they are being displayed on a certain domain's website. Referer can be faked, so it's not a particularly reliable security method. `SourceVPC` restricts access so that it only comes from a particular VPC (not the Internet). Using both of them together doesn't make much sense. Can you explain _WHY_ you want this, rather than saying that you want a VPC condition?

Comment: I can't wget image from my server. And i can&#39;t put my server public IP on this condition because there is auto scaling in my EC2  i want to put my vpc on that condition so that i can wget image from my EC2 instances

Comment: Hope you understand the situation

Comment: It is for simple user not for hackers.  And for vpc condition i want it so that i can't wget images from my EC2 instances. I can't put my public ips of my EC2 instances   in this policy because there is auto scaling enabled on my EC2. that's why i am putting vpc condition in my policy.

Comment: I suggest you create a new Question and clearly explain what you are attempting to achieve, what you have tried and what difficulties you are experiencing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172192/discussion-between-satish-gupta-and-john-rotenstein).